# How to do distinct join on more than 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Application 
  ( 
     ID_Application  INT, 
     ID_Owner1 INT,
     ID_Owner2 INT,
     ID_Owner3 INT,
     Name varchar(200) NOT NULL
  ); 

CREATE TABLE `Person` 
  ( 
     ID_Person  INT, 
     Name varchar(200) NOT NULL
  ); 

CREATE TABLE `PersonInOrg` 
  ( 
     ID_Person  INT, 
     ID_Org  INT
  ); 

CREATE TABLE `Org` 
  ( 
     ID_Org  INT,
     ID_Owner1 INT,
     ID_Owner2 INT,
     ID_Owner3 INT,
     Name varchar(200) NOT NULL
  ); 

INSERT INTO Application 
            (ID_Application, ID_Owner1, ID_Owner2, ID_Owner3, Name) 
VALUES      ( 123,11,21,null,"A"),
            ( 124,11,null,32,"B"),
            ( 125,11, null,null,"C");

INSERT INTO Person 
            (ID_Person, Name) 
VALUES      ( 12345,"Peter"),
            ( 12346,"Rafi"),
            ( 12347,"Rafael");
            
INSERT INTO PersonInOrg 
            (ID_Person, ID_Org) 
VALUES      ( 12345,1234),
            ( 12346,1111),
            ( 12347,1212);

INSERT INTO Org 
            (ID_Org, ID_Owner1, ID_Owner2, ID_Owner3, Name) 
VALUES      ( 1234,11,21,null,"Org1"),
            ( 1111,12,null,32,"Org2"),
            ( 1212,13, null,null,"Org3");
```

[Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bddf40/17/0)
I want to see the list of owners for all applications. The below picture explains the relations between the lists of tables.

------>**Application**

ID_Application; ID_Owner1; ID_Owner2; ID_Owner3;Name

------>**Person**
ID_Person; Name

------->**PersonInOrg**

ID_Person; ID_Org

------->**Org**

ID_Org; ID_Owner1; ID_Owner2; ID_Owner3; Name

**Expected result** -->List of applications with names for each owner as below:

ID_Application;ID_Owner1; ID_Owner2; ID_Owner3; ID_Person_1; ID_Person_2;   ID_Person_3

```
SELECT a.id_application, 
       a.id_owner1, 
       a.id_owner2, 
       a.id_owner3, 
       p.id_person AS [ID_Person1], 
       p.id_person AS [ID_Person2], 
       p.id_person AS [ID_Person3]
FROM   application AS a 
JOIN   org         AS o 
ON     a.id_owner1 = o.id_owner1 
OR     a.id_owner2 = o.id_owner2 
OR     a.id_owner3 = o.id_owner3 
JOIN   pesoninorg AS po 
ON     o.id_org = po.id_org 
JOIN   person AS p 
ON     po.id_org = p.id_person
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFeAi.png)

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS, only tag the one you are *really* using. As for your question. Sample data and expected results will greater help us help you.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Larnu - I have already wrote the code and what the expected result should like. The issue lies in the columns [ID_Person2] & [ID_Person2] as I dont know how or what joint should I make as these values doesnot exist in table PERSON

Comment: There is *no* sample data or expected results in your question. @AbdullahYusufAzzam , you have not shown us what the results should look like. As for the columns `ID_Person1`, `ID_Person2` and `ID_Person3`, they will all have the same value; they're just different aliases for the column `id_person` in the table `person`.

Comment: @Larnu added sample data

Comment: So what RDBMS are you using? Edit tags to show. Should normalize Application and Org tables so normal relationship joins can be utilized. Then will probably need CROSSTAB query to produce the non-normalized output.

Comment: Please don't post images of data, @AbdullahYusufAzzam , we can't use it. The data is text and should be supplied as text. Sample data is best supplied as DDL and DML statements, or otherwise tabular formatted `text`. It should not be images as you're then asking the users you're asking for help from to transcribe it for you; which is something that is far easier for you than us.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry --Thank you all for your feedback. Added the fiddle link

Comment: @Larnu added the link for fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Query1: AppUNION

```
SELECT ID_Application, ID_Owner1 AS Owner, 1 AS Seq FROM Application
UNION SELECT ID_Application, ID_Owner2, 2 FROM Application
UNION SELECT ID_Application, ID_Owner3, 3 FROM Application;
```

Query2: OrgPIO_UNION

```
SELECT Org.ID_Org, ID_Owner1 AS OwnerID, ID_Person, "ID_Person1" AS Seq FROM Org
    INNER JOIN PersonInOrg ON Org.ID_Org = PersonInOrg.ID_Org
UNION SELECT Org.ID_Org, ID_Owner2, ID_Person, "ID_Person2" FROM Org
    INNER JOIN PersonInOrg ON Org.ID_Org = PersonInOrg.ID_Org
UNION SELECT Org.ID_Org, ID_Owner3, ID_Person, "ID_Person3" FROM Org
    INNER JOIN PersonInOrg ON Org.ID_Org = PersonInOrg.ID_Org;
```

Query3: AppPersonCROSS

```
TRANSFORM First(OrgPIO_UNION.ID_Person) AS FirstOfID_Person
SELECT AppUNION.ID_Application
FROM AppUNION INNER JOIN OrgPIO_UNION ON AppUNION.Owner = OrgPIO_UNION.OwnerID
GROUP BY AppUNION.ID_Application
PIVOT OrgPIO_UNION.Seq;
```

Query4:

```
SELECT Application.*, ID_Person1, ID_Person2, ID_Person3
FROM AppPersonCROSS 
INNER JOIN Application ON AppPersonCROSS.ID_Application = Application.ID_Application;
```